# Convert Integer to Numeric with Replacement rules

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, replacement

I have a long list of triples, each looking something like `{AGO, 1988, 2345.23}`. Some of these, however, have an integer in the third spot, like this: `{IND, 1993, 4345}` because of the nature of the original data. I do not want integers, because I have to Log this data eventually.

So I thought I would map the following function through my list:

```
fn[s_List] :=  s //. {a_, b_, c_} /; IntegerQ[c] -> {a, b, N[c]}
```

It does not work. I want it to put "4345." in place of "4345".

However, I can use the following to get a very good approximation:

```
fnn[s_List] :=  s //. {a_, b_, c_} /; IntegerQ[c] -> {a, b, c-.00001}
```

But, even though the loss of precision is not important for this project, I'd like to know why my first function does not work.

I have been working with these kinds of replacement rules a lot recently, and this one seems pretty simple.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `fn[s_List] := s //. {a_, b_, c_} /; IntegerQ[c] :> {a, b, 1. c}`

Comment: In addition to what @belisarius said, the `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) should be unnecessary.  Try `ReplaceAll` (`/.`).

Comment: Here's a clean way: `fn[s_List] := s /. {a_, b_, c_Integer} :> {a, b, N@c}`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yep. My blinkers only allowed me to see the IntegerQ thing :)

Comment: Just for the record, `N@list` or `MapAt[N, list, {All, 3}]` also works.

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question has an answer, the following works:

```
lis = {{ago, 1988, 2344}, {bgy, 1980, 6654.5}, {ccr, 1999, 646}};
```

Now define:

```
fn[s_List] := s /. {a_, b_, c_} /; IntegerQ[c] :> {a, b, N@c}
```

Then:

```
fn[lis]
```

Gives:

```
{{ago, 1988, 2344.}, {bgy, 1980, 6654.5}, {ccr, 1999, 646.}}
```

Here is a shorter, cleaner way to achieve the same thing:

```
fn[s_List] := s /. {a_, b_, c_Integer} :> {a, b, N@c}
```